# Ingresar datos con SQL SERVR en node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs

Me gustaria que alguien me de un ejemplo de como puedo ingresar datos una base de datos SQL SERVER desde Node.js por favor!

Gracias :)

Comment: Hola, te sugiero modificar tu pregunta en base al documento [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He utilizado esta librería para SQLServer muchas veces, se llama [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) y no tengo problemas

Antes de comenzar debes tener una instancia de SQL funcionando, y las credenciales con las que harás cualquier función, ya sea un [CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) o ejecución de un [SP](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp).

Primero que todo debes instalar la librería usando:

```
npm install mssql
```

Definir la configuración

```
const config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost', //IP o Nombre de equipo según conf. del MSSQL
    database: '...' //Nombre de la BD
}
```

En una función que:

1. Abre la conexión.
2. Recibe parámetros.
3. Ejecuta un SP.
4. Cierra conexión.

Te sirve:

```
 exports.execSP = function(req, res)
    {
        console.log("(iExSP)LOG_:exec-SP");
        sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("(eExSP)LOG_:exec-SP"+err.originalError);
            res.status(500).send(err.originalError);
        }
        else
        {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.input('varOne', req.body.varTwo);
            request.input('varTwo', req.body.varTwo);
            request.execute('SP_Nombre', (err, result) => {
                if(err){console.log("LOG_:exec-SP"+' '+err.originalError.info.message);
                    res.status(500).send(err.originalError.info)}
                else
                {
                    if(result.recordsets[0].length == 0)
                    {
                        var recordsets = [{"msg":" No Data"}];
                        console.log("LOG_:exec-SP"+' '+recordsets[0].msg);
                        res.status(204).send(recordsets[0].msg)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("LOG_:exec-SP Data Sent");
                        res.status(200).send(result.recordsets[0])
                    }
                }
                sql.close()
            })  
        }                   
        })
    };
```